# Сортировка по категориям

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать список кортежей по статусу категории gold, затем silver, bronze и basic.

```
users = [("mary", "gold"), ("alex", "bronze"), ("michael", "silver"), ("gregory", "basic")]
```

Подскажите, как правильно создать функцию, по которой произвести сортировку.

Answer (score 3):

```
users = [("mary", "gold"), ("alex", "bronze"), ("michael", "silver"), ("gregory", "basic")]
sorted_users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: ("gold", "silver", "bronze", "basic").index(x[1]))
print(sorted_users)
```